# NoSuchMethodError error coming while running testcase

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I am facing a weird error.I have set up my code in IntelliJ Idea.

While running a test case I am getting the following erro

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler.addAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

 transformerHandler.getTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(sourceFile), result);
```

It seems to be a serializer error.I tried removing that too, but I am not able to get rid of this error.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is typically because the compile-time classpath doesn't match the run-time classpath, so a method that was present when you compiled isn't present when you run. Check your IntelliJ project configuration.

It's a Java problem, nothing to do with XML at all.

Comment: I even checked my configurations but everything went in vain.I am not getting why it is a problem as I have all the jars in place.

Comment: You have my sympathy. It's tough to debug these problems. One reason is that it's impossible to collect together the information that someone would need to help you on StackOverflow.

Comment: Actaully this problem came because of mis-match between xalan and xerces jar version.I found that there we 4 versions of transform method in my workspace(in different modules).As I was using xalan 2.7.1,I reverted it to 2.7.0 and it worked.